# Get Valdiation error in Tooltip if there is an error, else show explanatory Tooltip (using TextBox Style)

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

**Update: Found a Solution, see below!**

I'm try to implement the following behavior:

There are several TextBoxes in a UserControl. Each TextBox-ToolTip should show a specific string, which is located in a Resource.resx-file.
If the Valdiation of this TextBox returns an error, the returned error string will be shown in the ToolTip.
This should be done using a Style. My current status is, that I can show the specific Validation.Errors AND a *default* ToolTip, which is the same for every TextBox which uses the Style.

So my Style is :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"> 
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="ExampleToolTip"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                 Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

With this Style, i get the behavior described above.

Now I want the Style part

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"> 
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="ExampleToolTip"/>
    ...
</Style>
```

to be TextBox-Specific.

I tried to write an Attatched Property for my TextBoxes, so that I can define a second string, which should be used as the standard ToolTip.

The Attached Property Code ist shown below:

```
public class TextBox2 : DependencyObject
    {
        public static void SetToolTipStandard(TextBox target, string value)
        {
            target.SetValue(ToolTipStandardProperty, value);
        }

        public static string GetToolTipStandard(TextBox target)
        {
            return (string)target.GetValue(ToolTipStandardProperty);
        }

        public static DependencyProperty ToolTipStandardProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ToolTipStandard",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(TextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata());
    }
```

Now I want to set a TextBox2.ToolTipStandard property on my TextBoxes in XAML, and the TextBox-Style should take this Property to set the default ToolTip-Text. I tried several combinations of Bindings but with no success. Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the desired behaviour by naming all my TextBoxes and adding multiple Triggers to my TextBox-Style. Code follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!--Here are the static resource strings for the normal-state ToolTip-->
                <Trigger Property="Name" Value="TextBox1">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Static properties:UIStrings.TextBox1_ToolTip_String}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Name" Value="TextBox2">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Static properties:UIStrings.TextBox2_ToolTip_String}"/>
                </Trigger> ...

                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea, you can put a hidden border in the `ControlTemplate` with a `BorderThickness` of 0 around the input control which provides the error tooltip. If there is an error you set the visibility to visible and the error tooltip is shown.

It's just an idea, but it may work.